# How to show BBC Olympic RSS in iphone app

Tags: iphone, rss

I  am new to iPhone developing. I want to integrate BBC Olympic RSS feeds into my iPhone app. Is there any helpful resource that can help me out.

BBC Olympic RSS Feed:- http://www.bbc.co.uk/sport/0/1589034

this is the right rss feed url to be used

http://newsrss.bbc.co.uk/rss/sportonline_uk_edition/olympics/london_2012/rss.xml

Comment: http://www.raywenderlich.com/2636/how-to-make-a-simple-rss-reader-iphone-app-tutorial

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can use GDataXml for parsing the xml, find a simple application which demonstrates xml parse.

http://dl.dropbox.com/u/58723521/XMLParse.zip